# Call a WebService if value not found in an XML result

Tags: talend

From a MySQL query, I am trying to iterate on every rows to:

1. Test the existence of an object using a webservice
2. Then if the object doesn't exist yet, I will add it using another webservice, otherwise I do nothing.
3. Update in any case a MySQL DB table.

Here is what I've done so far:

[image]

- First I create the connection
- I get the columns I need from my MySQL query
- I start iterating
- I call my webservice which give me a **String** holding XML (column name: ResultXML)
  [image]
- I extract from this XML the values I need (column name: ResultExtract)
- Then I want to test if one of the values extracted is equal to a specific value (let's say 10).

So from my my **tExtractXMLField**, I get something like :

> 150
>
> 10

So this would mean that I won't have called the 2nd webservice.

I can't find how to look for my value in the result (the result can also be empty and then no row would come from the **tExtractXMLField**).
I tried to use a **tJava** after the **tExtractXMLField** component to split my result as a List but the **tJava** component is running before the 1st webservice has finished so I get NULL.

Maybe there is a better way to do what I've already done, and if so, I am also pleased to receive your recommandation.